# relationship of an instantiated class - Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, rest, api, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm working on an api for a website, where I have the tables of blogs and categories

every blog belongs to category
and each category has many blogs
OK?

So, I created a BlogController and configured the routes to access the corresponding function.

`/api/blog/` url via GET is redirected to the index function of my controller, and the function looks like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $blog = Blog::with('category')->get();
    return response()->json($blog, 200);
}
```

which returns this (correct)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "title from blog",
        "body": "texto do meu blog",
        "category_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-09-05 21:08:21",
        "updated_at": "2018-09-05 21:08:21",
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Web development",
            "created_at": "2018-09-05 20:54:54",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-05 20:54:54"
        }
    }
]
```

`/api/blog/` url via POST is redirected to the store function of my controller, to store the data in the database and the function looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $blog = new Blog($request->all());
    $saved = $blog->save();

    if ($saved) {
        return response()->json($blog, 200);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => '400 Bad Request'
    ], 400);
}
```

then returns (missing category information)

```
{
    "title": "title from blog",
    "body": "texto do meu blog",
    "category_id": "2",
    "updated_at": "2018-09-06 00:56:13",
    "created_at": "2018-09-06 00:56:13",
    "id": 12
}
```

then, missing category information

after storing data in the database, I need it to come in response to category information for that specific blog

someone to help?

Comment: figures, why the `index` function returns category information is due to `Blog::with('category')`. while the `store` function only returns the object only. you can use `$blog->loadMissing('category')` to load the relation, see the [docs regarding Lazy Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading).

Comment: I got it, thanks Bagus Tesa

Answer (score 0):

I can with

```
$blog->load('category');
```